# Looking for a way to access Google Apps mailboxes

Tags: gmail, google-apps

It seems like Google Apps apps don't have a way to access Google Apps Mail if you read the [API-definitions](http://code.google.com/intl/sv/apis/gdata/docs/developers-guide.html).

But still, [this applications](http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=5941+16825965296321823984) says it can backup Google Apps Mail.

Is there anyone who knows about these APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2010/03/oauth-authentication-for-google-mail.html) we go.